# Change font in a cell based on a value

Tags: vba, excel, fonts

I am trying to change the font in a range of cells depending on the value of these cells. So, I'd like to change the font of D1 depending on D1's value, and I'd like to change the font of D2 depending on D2's value, and so on up to D33.

I was able to find results for how to change the font of A CELL depending on the value of another cell [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/163988-color-index.html). This VBA code did the job for D1 only. However, it did not work for D2, D3, D4 and so on.

Could someone help me adjust that code to my need?

I apologize if this question is so easy to answer, but I'm not familiar with how VBA coding works.

Comment: (a) Why not just use conditional formatting?  (b) As none of the code on the linked page appears relevant to formatting of cell D1, can you please include in the question the code that you actually tried.  It will be easiest if we fix **your** code than try to write something from scratch which may or may not fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you've described, in this case applying a font to the text in column C based upon the special characters you mention in column D (Notice that I'm using 1 rather than "1", etc...).  If Column D doesn't contain any of those characters, it assumes the desired font name is in column D -- I did this just to provide a test of the code. Of course, you'll need to modify the code for your particular situation, but hopefully this gets you started.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub fontChange()
Dim theRange As Range, cell As Range
Set theRange = Range("C1:C16")
For Each cell In theRange
  Select Case cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Case 0, 1, "(":
      cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
    Case "", ":":
      cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    Case Else:
      cell.Font.Name = cell.Offset(0, 1)
  End Select
Next
End Sub
```

In the animated gif I step through the code so you can see it working.

Comment: Hi Tony,

Thanks for your reply and my apologies for late reply. I am trying to change the fonts of the cell in column D based on its value. I have formulas in D that returns the following characters:

"*","(", "1" or "0" (all of these characters don't have quotation marks).
I'd like to change the font to Wingdings 2 if a cell value in column D is "1" or "0" or "(". However, if it's ":" or "*", I'd like the font to change to Wingdings. I might need to add a third font later on. Can you please help me?

Comment: I've modified the code based upon your further definition of the question.  Hope it helps